# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lowagie.text.Document

Tags: java, android, noclassdeffounderror, android-droidtext

I've been using droidText.0.2.jar in my app for creating pdf files and it worked great. Today I updated eclipse and all of a sudden I get the following error "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.lowagie.text.Document" I checked the compiler settings and it appears to be set to JDK 1.6. I desperately need to get this fixed asap and I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: did you check your build path to ensure the jar is still there?

Comment: I did, even removed it and added it again with no avail. The problem seems to be with the update to eclipse itself. I found the fix here http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17 same issue with different jar files. hope this helps others.